# C++11: Is there a way to enforce class to be used only as rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I design a class, which should always exist only as rvalue. always.

What's the best approach to ensure that instances of this class would never appear in the code as lvalue?

If there is no such way, what would be the closest way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make all the relevant functions of your class rvalue-qualified:

```
struct Foo
{
    void frob(int a, int b) &&;
};
```

Usage:

```
Foo x;
// x.frob(1, 2);          // Error
std::move(x).frob(1, 2);  // Fine

Foo().frob(1, 2);         // Fine
```

The question as stated doesn't really make sense, because you can create any value category in any context, unrelated to any kind of class design. For example:

```
template <typename T> T & stay(T && x) { return x; }

stay(Foo());   // lvalue
```

So rather than worrying about how users can *obtain* values, it is probably more effective to constrain how users can *use* the values.

Comment: `x` is an lvalue... does that not count?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm describing an approach that may solve the OP's problem rather than answer her literal question... ("closest way to achieve this").

Comment: @Kerrek SB so using rvalue-qualified would be the closest approach ?(but cannot be applied to destructors, right ? otherwise it would be perfect)

Comment: @GabiMe: Special member functions are special, and it usually doesn't make sense to think about them as ordinary member functions. Naturally `{ const X x; }` should work, and you cannot const-qualify the destructor, just to give another example. You should probably describe your real problem rather than rushing into what you think is the solution.

Comment: **+1** for the last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible.
If you can describe the problem you're trying to solve, someone might be able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Foo {
  template<typename... Args>
  static Foo make_rvalue(Args&&... args) { return {std::forward<Args>(args)...}; }
private:
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(Foo const&) = default;
  Foo(Foo &&) = default;
  Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = default;
  Foo& operator=(Foo &&) = default;
};
```

The only way to make a value of this type persist is through reference lifetime extension: outside of `Foo`, it is invalid to say `Foo f(???);` for any expression `???`.

Create a new rvalue instance of `Foo`, bind it to the rvalue reference `f`.  Note that during its lifetime, use of `f` is treated as an lvalue:

```
Foo&& f = Foo::make_rvalue();
```

Here, we create an rvalue `Foo`, then move-construct another rvalue `Foo` with it, then bind it:

```
Foo&& f2 = Foo::make_rvalue( Foo::make_rvalue() );
```

Any other constructors will automatically work with `make_rvalue`.  Just keep them private.

You could also make `make_rvalue` a free function.  Friend it within `foo`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T make_rvalue( Args&&... args ) {
  return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

so it can access your `private` constructors:

```
Foo&& f = make_rvalue<Foo>();
```

which I think is a prettier syntax (and, `make_rvalue` can be used for other types for free).

A downside is that all of your constructors must be implicit, as `{}` construction requires implicit construction.  You could instead rely on RVO and copy/move construction I suppose.